# button on click event does not fire if active textarea has css to change size on focus

Tags: javascript, html, css, focus

As you can test in snippet if i focus textarea and click on button no action fires, i have to click one more time

removing focus style all works fine.

what can i do?
thanks

```css
textarea:focus{
  height:5rem;
}
```

```html
<textarea class="dx-texteditor-input" spellcheck="true" tabindex="0" role="textbox" aria-multiline="true"></textarea>

<button onclick="alert('ok');">
test
</button>
```

Comment: It's because clicking outside the textarea losing focus and causing the height to change. Meaning the button moves and doesn't get clicked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In short, the [UI Events specification](https://www.w3.org/TR/uievents/#event-type-click) explains a `click` for pointer devices as follows:

> The `click` event type MUST be dispatched on the ... target
> indicated by the pointer, when the user presses down
> and releases the primary pointer button ... .

In you example we press down on the button, the button moves, and we release *elsewhere* (not on the button). We don't fulfill the conditions for a `click` event to be dispatched!

**Ideally, UI elements shouldn't move during interactions.** And, *there is no need to resize the textarea* automatically on focus; the user can already resize it to their liking by default.

---

Should you want to resize it regardless, simply **position the button independently of the textarea**, e.g.:

```css
.text-box {
  display: inline-grid;
  grid-auto-flow: column;
  align-items: start;
}

textarea:focus{height: 5rem}
```

```html
<div class="text-box">
  <textarea></textarea>
  <button onclick="alert('ok');">test</button>
</div>
```

Or **delay the change in textarea's height** to a reasonable amount. Example via CSS:

```css
textarea {
  /* Can only transition to/from computable <length>s, meaning:
   * Must be set to a computable <length-percentage>.
   */
  height: 2lh;
  
  transition-delay: 1s;
  transition-property: height;
}
textarea:focus {
  height: 5rem;
  
  /* When :focus, don't delay:
   * This applies the new height immediately.
   */
  transition-delay: 0s;
}
```

```html
<textarea></textarea>
<button onclick="alert('ok');">test</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

the problem is that your button moves when you `onfocus` the `textarea`, that's why the button wont be clicked.

to fix that use the code below:

```js
function ok() {
  document.getElementById("txta").blur() 
  alert("ok")
}
```

```css
#txta-container {
  min-height: 6rem;
}

textarea:focus {
  height: 5rem;
}
```

```html
<div id="txta-container">
  <textarea id="txta" class="dx-texteditor-input" spellcheck="true" tabindex="0" role="textbox" aria-multiline="true"></textarea>
</div>
<button id="btn" onclick="ok()"> test </button>
```